# Snort automatic protocol detection

Tags: ids, snort

Does Snort have the "automatic protocol detection" function like Suricata? I read that Snort 3 has "Autodetect services for portless configuration" feature. Does it mean that this function is absent in Snort 2? Or they are completely different functions?

Comment: I googled your question and got this as the top hit: https://suricata.readthedocs.io/en/suricata-4.1.3/rules/differences-from-snort.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technology is called OpenAppID. It is present in Snort since 2.9.7 - see [this presentation](https://snort-org-site.s3.amazonaws.com/production/document_files/files/000/000/066/original/OpenAppID-Community-Webinar.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIXACIED2SPMSC7GA%2F20200622%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200622T151704Z&X-Amz-Expires=172800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=4f2475a2aea8ac36c78c50390a05ec1291918b516d7c5673bcb33f644512d4bf) from 2015 or [this announcement](https://blogs.cisco.com/security/cisco-announces-openappid-the-next-open-source-game-changer-in-cybersecurity) from 2014.